# Proving that $4n^2 - 1$ is divisible by 3.

Tags: number-theory, induction

I apologise (apologize for my American friends :)) if I have overlooked something simple which I am sure is the case.

#### Unnecessary background:

This came up when trying to prove a related assertion (which for all intents and purposes is not needed for this question) and after trying a few cases it seemed that when multiplying any square number by $4$ the result was always one more than $3k$.

tl;dr tried stuff and noticed stuff :P

Anyways,

#### I am trying to prove that $4n^2 - 1$ is divisible by $3$

So I thought induction would be our weapon of choice.

For n = 1, the case is trivial, as $4\times1^2 - 1 = 3 = 3\times 1$

Now, suppose $4n^2 - 1 = 3k$ then $4n^2 = 3k+1$

Now we prove for $n+1$
i.e. $4(n+1)^2 - 1 = 4n^2 +8n +3 $

but we know $4n^2 = 3k+1$ so $3k+8n+4$ should equal $3r$

But clearly it doesn't :/
Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Not if $n$ is divisible by $3$, but yes otherwise.

Comment: Ah darn I missed that. I guess I was not thinking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is that the statement you try to prove is false: If $n=3$ then $4n^2-1 = 35$ is not a multiple of $3$. To do the rest you could try induction in steps of $3$ (i.e. $n\to n+3$). Or show that $n(4n^2-1)$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Precisely my line of thought after I struggled with the proof for some time!

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach:

Note that $$4n^2 - 1 = (2n - 1)(2n+1)$$

Consider the three consecutive numbers $(2n - 1), 2n, (2n+1)$. Exactly of those three terms can be divisible by $3$.

Now, if $n$  is not divisible by $3$, then neither is $2n$, so exactly one of the two factors $(2n-1)$ or $(2n+1)$ must be, and hence, $(4n^2 - 1) = (2n-1)(2n+1)$ is necessarily divisible by $3$.

Comment: Why can't $2n$ be divisible by $3$? Consider $n=3,$ for example.

Comment: $2n$ is not divisible by 3 if $n$ is not, this was a conditional statement.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $4n^2-1=(2n)^2-1=(2n-1)(2n+1)$. But among the three consecutive integers $2n-1$, $2n$ and $2n+1$, exactly one can be divided by $3$.

More generally, $m^2-1$ is divisible by $3$ iff $m$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

If $n \equiv 0,1,2\mod 3$, then $4n^2-1\equiv2,0,0\mod3$.

Comment: This is how I would solve this.